# Retry requests that timeout using angular $resource inside the failure callback

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Im trying to retry a request that failed due to a timeout or some other reason. I want to do this inside the failure callback without having to use any interceptor. Is that possible?

```
$resource(url, {}, {get: {method: "GET"}}).get()
                        .$promise.then(function (res) {
                           //Success callback
                        }, function (err) {
                           //Failure callback 
                           //Retry the same request here!!
                        });
```

Comment: Have you tried by calling $resource.get() again?

Answer (score 0):

You could define an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) and make use of it from a `transformResponse` hook on [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

```js
/* First, define the Interceptor */
angular.module('MyModule').factory('MyInterceptor', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
  return {
    responseError: function(res) {
      return $injector.get('$http')(res.config); /* Try again. Inject dependency here to avoid circular dependency for $http */
    }
  }
}])
```

```js
/* Then use define the resource */
const MyModel = $resource(url, {}, {
  get: {
    method: "GET",
    transformResponse: [null, MyInterceptor], /* trigger on error only */
  }
});
```